# How to deal with recursive hashcodes

Tags: java, recursion, tree, hashcode

I'm trying to create a proper `hashCode` (and `equals`) implementation for some classes that link eachother.

Example:

- Object 1 (parent)

  - List of children
- Object 2 (child)

  - Parent

If I were to create a `hashCode` of each field of these objects, an infinite loop would occur: the `hashCode` of the parent depends on its children; the `hashCode` of a child depends on its parent.

How do I solve this problem? I can't just ignore one of the fields. In my implementation parents have names, so right now I'm using a parents `name` field to hash instead of hashing the whole object. This is error prone though since objects may have the same name but not the same children.

Edit: I can't just ignore the parent since children may be structurally identical except for their parent: and then the are not equal since they are in a different position in the data structure. This question is not a duplicate.

Comment: Calculate the hashcode of the child ignoring the parent.

Comment: This causes unacceptable collisions in my code.

Comment: Use the parent's [identity hashcode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode(java.lang.Object))?

Comment: just out of curiosity. how did you implement equals? It is recursive too?

Comment: @AndyTurner that would nullify the usefulness of overriding `equals`, since it would return false when in fact the objects a structurally equal.

Comment: @dehasi It has the same problem, since 
`If two objects are equal, then they must have the same hash code.`